# Why do bootstrap 5 cards break with scrollable content in them?

Tags: css, flexbox, overflow, bootstrap-5

I put together the following pen to illustrate my problem: https://codepen.io/ganakim/pen/jOKmByM

For some reason, even though column 1 has `overflow-y: auto` it doesn't scroll, and instead forces the footer outside the max height of the card. How do I fix this?

Comment: You're using `max-height` randomly, also you put `height: 200px` in the `.wrapper` class, why? Which part do you want to scroll? Please describe the issue clearly.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

## Bootstrap only solution (no CSS)

As @Dakshank suggested, you should add `overflow: hidden` to the parent element (i.e., `card-body`).

#### But...

If you're using Bootstrap, then it's considered good practice to use Bootstrap classes in order to achieve your goal. Why writing CSS, if you can achieve the same goal with Bootstrap classes?

See the snippet below.

```css
.wrapper {
  height: 200px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue
}

.card {
  max-height: 80%;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-rbsA2VBKQhggwzxH7pPCaAqO46MgnOM80zW1RWuH61DGLwZJEdK2Kadq2F9CUG65" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-kenU1KFdBIe4zVF0s0G1M5b4hcpxyD9F7jL+jjXkk+Q2h455rYXK/7HAuoJl+0I4" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex overflow-hidden">
      <div class="w-30 overflow-auto">
        Col 1
        <br> More Col 1
        <br> More Col 1
        <br> More Col 1
        <br> More Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="w-30">
        Col 2
      </div>
      <div class="w-30">
        Col 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Huh, and here I thought if you set the overflow to hidden, then it wouldn't attempt to scroll. Thank you very much for enlightening me!

Answer (score 0):

Got it. Many times i had the same problem but i came to know solution to this very early stage of flex.

Simply add `overflow: hidden` or `min-height: 0` to the parent element where the scroll accures. This works all the time when there you want to add overflow to the child where you want to keep scroll height dynamic.

I hope this helps.

```css
.wrapper{
  height: 200px;
  background-color: cornflowerblue
}

.card{
  max-height: 80%;
}

.scroll-y{
  max-height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card-body{
  overflow: hidden;
  /* and there is another option */
  /* min-height: 0; */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap/5.0.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-header">
      Header
    </div>
    <div class="card-body d-flex">
      <div class="w-30 scroll-y">
        Col 1
        <br>
        More Col 1
        <br>
        More Col 1
        <br>
        More Col 1
        <br>
        More Col 1
      </div>
      <div class="w-30">
        Col 2
      </div>
      <div class="w-30">
        Col 3
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
      Footer
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```